# How to use binary-only package with "go get"

Tags: go, import, binary, package, goimports

My binary package have some dependencies installed from `go get` command.
After building and create sourcode with `//go:binary-only-package`

There are some errors like:

```
cannot find package github.com/robfig/cron (using -importcfg)
cannot find package github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware (using -importcfg)
```

How do i import binary-only package?

Comment: 1st. If you are using modules it's not going to work.
2nd. [Support](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28152) for binary-only packages is going to an end.
3rd: Russ Cox [suggests](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28152#issuecomment-431368339) using plugins as a replacement for binary-only packages.

Comment: @PiotrKowalczuk what are modules? You mean github packages? I want to separate framework part and source code part, framework is a binary package. Go plugin only work on Linux, so it doesn't help. The question is what can i do with github packages

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: @PiotrKowalczuk using plugin is the whole diference thing, your code will be 100 times longer https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28152#issuecomment-466670987, bad move for Go. Many other languages support a way of distributing packages that don't have the original source in them: C++, Swift